# How to write start of Excel Reporting into eventlog

Tags: excel, vba

I want Excel VBA to to write the start of when the macro starts into the eventlog. It is initiated through a server.

Comment: Eventlog means windows event logs?

Comment: No, theres a logfile on the Reporting server

Answer (score 3):

This will write a message to the Windows application event log:

```
Public Enum EventType
    xlLogSuccess = 0
    xlLogError = 1
    xlLogWarning = 2
    xlLogInformation = 4
    xlLogAudit_Success = 8
    xlLogAudit_Failure = 16
End Enum


Sub WriteEventLog(ByVal sLogMessage As String, Optional ByVal iLogType As Integer)
    Dim wso As Object
    Set wso = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wso.LogEvent iLogType, sLogMessage
End Sub


Sub Test()
    WriteEventLog "My log message", xlLogAudit_Success
End Sub
```

Comment: where is the EventLog located?

Comment: Really? Your question asked how to write to it... https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/

Comment: Could you explain the variables to me?

    xlLogSuccess = 0
    xlLogError = 1
    xlLogWarning = 2
    xlLogInformation = 4
    xlLogAudit_Success = 8
    xlLogAudit_Failure = 16

Comment: I've just declared an Enumerated variable, so that it's easier to identify the event type you're passing. `xlLogInformation` is more informative than `4` when writing / debugging. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms813548.aspx

Comment: Now I want to hand over the value of an in-script variable, I tried with 

WriteEventLog "Saved copy to target directory! ID: " & variable

but it doesnt work :/

Comment: the value doesn't get written into the eventlog, its just empty

Comment: Does the test sub in my answer successfully write to the event log?

Comment: no you get me wrong. every message i type is written fine into eventlog. but i want to hand over the value of a variable into the log, and the value of the variable doesn't get written into the log

Comment: Step through your code. Check your variable value, when you reach the `WriteEventLog` line.

Comment: Is it possible to call this sub procedure from a function? because i wanted to write some line WriteEventLog "running with SAP-Connection", xlLogAudit_Success out of a public function, but it didnt get written into the log

Comment: Public Function LogonBW() As Boolean
    If Environ("Testenvironment") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Testenvironment is 0, Testenvironment is off, running with SAP-Connection"
    WriteEventLog "running with SAP-Connection", xlLogAudit_Success
   
    ElseIf Environ("Testenvironment") = 1 Then
    WriteEventLog "running without SAP-Connection", xlLogAudit_Success
    MsgBox.Show "Testenvironment is 1, running without SAP-Connection"
    Exit Function
    'no SAP-conn
    
End Function

Comment: I want to check if Environmental variable is true or false. If it is false, it should run a connection to SAP - server. Is it true, then it should not run the connection. But there was no such Line in the event log, so I thought Calling Sub Procedures out of functions is not possible? Because the messages I wanted to have in the log weren't in the log

Comment: I also dont receive the MessageBox I want, but thats another story

Comment: That's really not another story... Your function code doesn't compile (no End If), and the fact no messageboxes are being displayed shows that the WriteLogEvent call is never being made. Please, learn to debug your code - try stepping through, and check the value of Environ("Testenvironment") at the If line. You'll probably find it is blank...

Comment: Ah, thanks, I realized that there was no End If, haha